# Assembly decision loops

Tags: computer-architecture

An high level language such as C has many statements for decision and loops while an assembly such the MIPS' one has few. With `slt`, `slti`, `beq`, `bne` it can create all conditions. What are the advantages and disadvantages of reducing the decision statements?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the subject?

Comment: Well, I think that, in line with the first design principle ("keep it simple"), few statements can favor regularity in low level operations. But, at the same time, this is apparently not true for at high level. The third design principle ("compromise") should justify this behavior, but I am looking for a more solid proof.

Answer (score 0):

Since C is a high level language in comparison to assembly level so yes they're required to have all those decision and loop statements for use at the appropriate places while the assembly level at its core breaks those statement to branches and loops using limited instructions and that is also foundational to RISC architecture.
Hope that helps.
P.S-Although there are many statements for decisions and loops in programming
languages like C and Java, the bedrock statement that implements them at the
instruction set level is the conditional branch.

Comment: `all those decision and loop statements`. Please name/choose a language standard: how many `decision and loop statements` can you enumerate?

Comment: https://www.tutorialcup.com/cprogramming/decision-making-and-loops.htm --Check it out. Hope that gives you some idea of the decision making and loops in C.